# How to define a variable with a list of files in a YAML file for Azure DevOps or GitHub

Tags: github-actions, azure-pipelines-yaml

How to avoid duplication of file lists in Azure DevOps / GitHub pipelines?

Suppose I have the following YAML file:

```
name: Build

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
    paths: 
      - 'SRC/define.inc'
      - 'SRC/SrvMain.pas'
      - 'SRC/Tiny.dpr' 
      - 'SRC/xBase.pas'

  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]
    paths: 
      - 'SRC/define.inc'
      - 'SRC/SrvMain.pas'
      - 'SRC/Tiny.dpr' 
      - 'SRC/xBase.pas'

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
```

*...skipped remaining lines...*

*[(I'm using this pipeline for the TinyWeb repository on GitHub)](https://github.com/maximmasiutin/TinyWeb/actions)*

As you see, the list of files under the `paths:` section repeats for the "push" and "pull_request" sections. How can I define a list of files just once, so I would not need to copy it to each of the sections, but only add a reference to the list variable? I've tried to define the list using the `variables:` keyword and then reference the list as `${{ variables.my_variable_name }}`, but it didn't work. I tried multiple variants to no avail.

Please give an example of the YAML file where I can define the list of files once and then use it from multiple sections under `on:`.

Answer (score 4):

Hi [@Maxim Masiutin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6910868/maxim-masiutin) I have tried with both `env` and `secrets` but it didn't work out. You are asking for using one path for both `push` and `pull_request` events and it is not possible for now. There is no statements that shows supporting for variables at workflow level. You can check [this](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpaths) for paths/paths_ignore.

However you are using both `push` and `pull_request` events exactly same I think you may use like below:

```yaml
name: Build

on:
  push:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]
    paths: 
      - 'SRC/define.inc'
      - 'SRC/SrvMain.pas'
      - 'SRC/Tiny.dpr' 
      - 'SRC/xBase.pas'

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
```

I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 4):

This syntax worked for me on Azure.

```
name: Build

variables:
  src_define: 'SRC/define.inc'
  src_srvmain: 'SRC/SrvMain.pas'
  src_tiny: 'SRC/Tiny.dpr'
  src_xbase: 'SRC/xBase.pas'

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
    paths: 
      - variables['src_define']
      - variables['src_srvmain']
      - variables['src_tiny']
      - variables['src_xbase']

  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]
    paths: 
      - variables['src_define']
      - variables['src_srvmain']
      - variables['src_tiny']
      - variables['src_xbase']

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
```